# Rewrite only root without redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a problem that I can't get to rewrite only root to file. For example example.com to example.com/landing-page/mypage.html but keep all other addresses like example.com/something/ intact.

Currently for test purposes I have managed to redirect /test/ and my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/.*$
RewriteRule . /wp-content/themes/mytheme/landing_page.html [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But now if I try to redirect only root and replace RewriteCond with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

it doesn't work and it loads my Wordpress site.

UPDATE:
I tested on another server using just simple rule `RewriteRule ^/?$ /mypage/landing-page.html [L]` also keeping WordPress lines and it works there, but the same lines do not work on this server. So now the question arises what server settings might be preventing this simple rule.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to turn on the RewriteEngine in your second example .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /landing-page/mypage.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: No, I have it. It was just meant as example showing only that line, that I don't have domain at the beginning.